# Removing MonetDB from Ubuntu 14.04 server and reinstalling it from source

Tags: monetdb

I want to uninstall monetdb from ubuntu 14.04 server platform so that i can install it again from the source. Also i want my db farm not to be removed while uninstalling the monetdb. How to acchieve this ?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04 server

Answer (score 2):

First make sure no MonetDB processes are running before removing the server. Running `monetdbd stop <dbfarm-location>` will stop `monetdbd` and `mserver5` processes on that *dbfarm*. To be sure, you can verify that `ps aux| grep monetdb` and `ps aux| grep mserver` show no processes.

If you installed it from the MonetDB repo (as suggested on the website), simply run `sudo apt-get autoremove monetdb5-sql`. This will uninstall the MonetDB server installed on a Ubuntu/Debian system - removing `monetdb5-sql` and the `monetdb5-server` packages, as well as all dependencies installed for them, but no-longer needed.

Any *dbfarms* will not be removed - the .deb package installer will not seek to delete any *dbfarms*. As long as the *dbfarm* was not created in the installation directory. To be certain, you can make a copy of your dbfarm at another location, e.g. in your home directory.